# Working flow of an OpenCL

Tags: opencl

I am just curious about the workflow of OpenCL. 
Does the OpenCL runtime does some kind of a JIT compilation?

I will explain the best of my understanding,

1. From the kernel file generate a SPIR file.
2. Then the host program requests the OpenCL runtime to execute the SPIR file.
3. The OpenCL runtime schedules and translate the SPIR into a form that each device can understand and then send it to the device.

If what I've explained is correct, then I think in #3, there should be some kind of JIT compilation for each devices. I think this is supported for portability, but doesn't this hurt performance?

Comment: Read the specs from Khronos. And yes, it's some kind of JIT.

Comment: It is not really a JIT because it compiles when the user calls the `createProgram()`, which can be at any time. But yes, it compiles after the application is running.